# Why does my mac keep showing the message “Your computer restarted because of a problem”?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, catalina, high-sierra

I tried to completely reset factory my MacBook so I cleared all the partitions via internet recovery mode according to Apple support tutorial.

[image]

Then I reinstalled macOS and all the download process was successful, but I keep getting [this message](https://pasteboard.co/JrMkJ8J.jpg) right after my mac downloading process gets completed and by the time the installation process is about to begin, this shows up.

This is how the partitions are organized:

[image: Disk Utility]

MacBook Pro 2017

I would appreciate if anyone can help me fix this.

Comment: I don't think you've got a valid OS on "Programmer", have you? I would try reinstalling the OS. (Which OS?) You could also try installing the OS onto an external disk, to see if it's the internal SSD that's the problem, or if the problem is with the installation process.

Comment: No, they're just the installation files downloaded via "reinstall mac" option in recovery mode, but as the system gets restarted to initialize the installation process the message above shows up on the screen.

Comment: Unfortunately the Panic screen does not show any information, just that the system Panic'ed. If it does that before it even boots there is likely something more wrong than a failed installation. Possibly hardware. Please add to your question at **EXACTLY** what point does the system Panic? EG, before or after your hold Command-R, before or after the Apple logo comes up, how far does the boot progress bar get, etc...

Comment: Thanks @SteveChambers for the insights. The message shows up right after the download progress - from internet recovery mode - gets completed and system spontaneously restarts to initialize installation. I can also get access to internet recovery mode before the panic and as I erase the entire drive this message would goes away too.

Comment: Hoping you found a resolution to this.. I'm running into the same issue now. Any insight?

Answer (score 2):

If you get that on a clean install, it’s likely you have hardware or a connected device that has failed and needs to be repaired or replaced.

Here is the official guide on when to look at software and when to get hardware support.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT200553

In your case - repair the SSD - not the volume in it called Programmer. And if you erase the drive - erase the SSD - not the volume under it named Programmer or Macintosh HD or whatever - the name doesn’t matter - it’s the placement as an object contained inside the drive that’s the difference.

Comment: I get this message on my screen just after the mac download process- in the "reinstall mac"- option gets completed and the MacBook gets restarted to initialize the installation progress. I'm also not seeing any OS partitions called Macintosh HD and Macintosh HD - data in the disk utility section. Does the problem have something to do with the partitions?

Comment: yes @Amir - go back and erase the entire drive if you have a backup. If you don’t have a backup - skip step 2 here, but do all the rest. Instead of step 2 - open disk utility and get a picture of your layout - select the top most drive itself and run First Aid. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904 - then install the OS on top of what you have.

Comment: Thanks @bmike I've actually tried this already and completely erased the top most drive and run first aid but unfortunately no luck so far! On the other hand, nothing seems to be wrong with my SSD as it used to function properly before I decided to entirely erase it and nothing seems to be wrong during "reinstall mac" process except for the message that shows up after the restart and by the time that the installation progress is about to begin.

Comment: The only thing that seems wrong to me is the fact that before I erase the entire top drive I had two partitions called Macintosh HD and Macintosh HD - data, but now I only have the programmer. I don't know if I should recreate those partitions or they are just names?

Comment: The Apple installer will recreate both partitions when it completes successfully. Your install failed to complete or you installed a much older OS than Catalina. @Amir

Comment: If you are getting kernel panics after a fresh install of macOS, you can rule out software issues. It’s most likely drive failure or logic board failure (I personally think it’s the logic board). You can check in ‘console.app’ to see what’s possibly causing the kernel panics. If it’s from 2017, depending on your country you may have statutory warranty that covers it, otherwise you’ll have to pay to get it fixed. To give you a rough price estimate, I had a Vintage 15” MBP 2013 2.6GHz quad core with 16GB RAM, replaced the logic board last year for about USD $600. Best of luck